# Ensuring Newly Spawned Child Processes Include Function Changes in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm starting a new child process by specifying a myFunction(), using spawn.
After editing the myFunction() and respawning the child process for the myFunction():
the newly spawned child process does not include changes to the myFunction().

I really do not want to put the function into a separate file and try to delete require/import caches.
Even if it all have some chance to work.

Maybe someone have some understanding on how I could ensure the newly spawned child would include the changes of myFunction()

This script starts a new child process using myFunction() as basis.
If myFunction() is modified and a new child process is started, the child process does not include changes of myFunction(). I need the changes to the function to exist in the new spawned child process.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const readline = require('readline');

function myFunction() {
  const { Client } = require('revolt.js');
  console.log('Child process is running');
  console.log('This is stdout');
  console.error('This is stderr');

  let client = new Client();

  client.on('ready', async () => console.info(`Logged in as ${client.user.username}!`));

  client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {

    if (message.content === 'ahello') {
      message.channel.sendMessage('123wworldffqqew');
    } else if (message.content === 'restart') {
        
      process.send('restart');
      message.channel.sendMessage('worldr');
    }
  });

  client.loginBot('YOUR_TOKEN');
}

let child;

function startChildProcess() {
    
    // Check what's passed before myFunction, it might be that myFunction is cached and not taked from the source file.
  child = spawn('node', ['-e', `(${myFunction.toString()})();`], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc'] });



  // Listen to stdout
  child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    process.stdout.write(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  // Listen to stderr
  child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    process.stderr.write(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  // Listen for the child process to exit
  child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log('Child process exited with code', code);
  });

  // Listen for messages from the child process
  child.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message === 'restart') {
      // Kill the current child process
      child.kill();
      
      delete require.cache[require.resolve("./nodetest.js")];

      // Start a new child process
      startChildProcess();
    }
  });
}

// Start the initial child process
startChildProcess();
```